# Node.js VSCode Debugger Missing Env Variables

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, environment-variables, dotenv

When I run the debugger in vscode I get this error:

```sh
MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
```

I realized this was because the debugger isn't getting access to my `.env` file. My database uri is stored in my `.env` file. So the debugger can't see it.

How can I give my debugger access to the my `.env` file variables?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I fixed it by adding this to my `launch.json` file in my `.vscode` workspace folder. I added two values to the configurations object:

```json
"env": { "PORT": "4000" },
"envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/backend/.env"
```